# seven thief and equal coins

Tags: mathematics

Seven thieves are to distribute a number of coins between themselves. They find that it splits equally, but being astute mathematicians, they realize that if there were 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6 thieves to split coins among, there would always be one coin left over. How many coins are there?

Comment: English is not my mother tongue, but this is damn hard to understand. Would you mind to paraphrase it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> 301

The math is below:

> 301/7 = 43
>  301/6 = 50 + 1/6
>  301/5 = 60 + 1/5
>  301/4 = 75 + 1/4
>  301/3 = 100 + 1/3
>  301/2 = 150 + 1/2